# for loop doesn't terminate in C

Tags: c

I am making program which extracts some part of a given string.
but its having some problem in the for loop in function `extct()`; the for loop is not terminating by `a<=b`. it just goes through it and terminating at only `a!='\0'`.

```
int main()
{
    void extct();
    char my_string[50];

    printf("Enter anything: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",my_string);

    extct(my_string);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void extct(char *a)
{
    int i,j,l;
    char new_string[50];

    printf("Enter location from you want to extract string: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Now enter no. of letters you want to extract from previous entered location: ");
    scanf("%d",&j);

    a=a+(i-1);    //sets address to entered location

    int b=a+j;  //sets limit for the for loop

    for(l=0;(a<=b)||(*a!='\0');a++,l++)
    {
        new_string[l]=*a;
    }
    new_string[l]='\0';
    printf("\n%s",new_string);

}
```

Comment: Debugger is the tool to use.

Comment: `true || false` evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to terminate the loop if any of the condition satisfies, then use `&&` instead of `||`

```
  for(l=0;(a<=b) && (*a!='\0');a++,l++)
```

Comment: @Barmar Why is that?

Comment: @SamIam Because it helps understand why you switch from `||` to `&&` when you're changing the sense of the condition.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think It's topical.  There's only one condition in the OP's code.  There's no indication that the OP had one condition in mind and decided to refactor it.

Comment: @SamIam You often think about the terminating conditions, like `*a = 0` or `a > b`. Then you have to invert them because `for` wants the continuing conditions. When you do that, you have to remember to invert the operator that joins them, and that's De Morgan's Law.